# fragment loss with ContourPlot3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I expect to have a chimney-look plot out of the function  `z = 1/(x^2 + y^2)`, but what I got is a broken one. Is there a way to get an intact plot from `ContourPlot3D` without any fragment loss?

```
ContourPlot3D[
 1/(x^2 + y^2) - z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -150, 150}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add more `PlotPoints`:

```
ContourPlot3D[1/(x^2 + y^2) - z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -150, 150}, 
 PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]